# unpack standalone node executable

Tags: node.js, npm, executable

A client has provided me a standalone `node` executable and I am required to  make some changes to the code. Apparently the previous developer didn't handover the full source for their application. I believe it's packed using [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg).
 Is there a way to extract the packed application and `.js` files ?
EDIT: the executable is `.exe`